# getting elements with a queryset based on a left join in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class B(models.Model):
    a_field = models.ForeignKey(null=True,blank=True,related_name='a',on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to get all of elements of model A which are not related to B.
Here is the query I wrote but it doesn't work:

```
B.objects.select_related("a_field").filter(a_field__isnull=True)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get all of elements of model `A` which are not related to `B`.

You can query with:

```
A.objects.filter(a=None)
```

The `a` origiates from the [**`related_name=…`** value <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for the `ForeignKey`, but it makes no sense to name that `'a'`, since it is the relation in *reverse*, so from `A` to `B`, usually it makes more sense to name that `'bs`', so:

```
class B(models.Model):
    a_field = models.ForeignKey(
        A,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='bs',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    # …
```

and thus query with:

```
A.objects.filter(bs=None)
```